# How to adjust position of textLabel, detailTextLabel and switch in tableview?

Tags: iphone

I have textLabel, detailTextLabel, UISwitch in tableview cell.
I want to adjust y position of them. How can I do that?
I already adjusted height of cell.

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 50, 30);
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
```

Above code doesn't work for switch. It always shows at the same position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add it as subView to cell 's content view like this:

`[[cell contentView] addSubView:switchView];` and switchView's x,y should be relative to tableViewCell.

Comment: I added [[cell contentView] addSubView:switchView]; but it makes no difference.

Comment: Did you comment out the line cell.accessoryView ?

Comment: I forgot to delete that line. I works now for switch. How about text and detailText?

Comment: @user698200 Likewise, [[cell contentView] addSubView:detailTextLabel]

Answer (score 1):

You can custom your own UITableViewCell say MyTableViewCell and adjust controls in layoutSubviews.

eg:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Adjust size
    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,44,44);

    // Adjust position
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x,
                                      self.textLabel.frame.origin.y - 10,
                                      self.textLabel.frame.size.width,
                                      self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
```

}